# Adding a view over the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, footer

I have to create a screen that looks like this.

[image]

I have almsot accomplished it using a `UITableViewController`. The reason I went that route instead of using a `UIViewController` along with a `UIScrollView` is that, the table view in the middle is static and only `UITableViewControllers` can have static table views. Anyway my current result is this.

[image]

The table's header view contains the labels at the top and the footer view contains the map view.

I created a separate `UIView` subclass with a nib called `ButtonView` for the two buttons.

```
import UIKit

class ButtonView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var declineButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var acceptButton: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ButtonView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.bounds = view.bounds
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ButtonView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }
}
```

And I tried adding it to the table view controller's `view` and then `tableView` but both times it gets added to the scroll view instead. I want those buttons to be fixed to the bottom. So I added them to the `window`.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var buttonView: ButtonView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 35, right: 0)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        buttonView = ButtonView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - 35, width: view.frame.width, height: 35))
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(buttonView)
    }
}
```

But as you can see from the screenshot above, the buttons' width is off. They haven't resized properly to fit the screen. I have set all the necessary auto layout constraints in the `ButtonView`.

[image]

How can I get them to resize and fit the screen properly?

Comment: I get this error. **error: Illegal Configuration: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances**.

Comment: Just use a container view to embed the tableviewcontroller in your standard ViewController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest going a different route. Put your `UITableviewController` in a container view in a normal view controller. It gives you the best of both worlds. Your parent VC can have whatever views you want, and the contained `UITableviewController` manages your static table view for you.

Here is a link to a sample project doing exactly that: (in Objective-C, but the concept and layout is identical.)

https://github.com/DuncanMC/test

### EDIT:

As @Gordonium alludes to in his answer, adding views in code but not setting constraints rarely gives the results you want. If you add views in code and you're using AutoLayout then you also need to add a set of constraints that specifies the size and spacing of your views. It's usually easier to set up the views and their constraints using IB .

Answer (score 2):

Here you go - I've setup a basic project for you.

You can get it here: https://github.com/99arobe/ButtonTest

It uses a container and autolayout so it should get you started. It roughly looks like this:

[image]

There are probably a few ways of doing this, but the moment that you start setting view's frames in code you won't receive the benefits of autolayout unless you manually add that code as well.

Comment: And when you set views' frames in code, AutoLayout often takes over and undoes your changes.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I often see people changing the device's orientation and wondering why their view has suddenly shot to x0, y0.

Comment: @Gordonium Thanks for the detailed answer and the demo project. Since both yours and Duncan's answers are the same but he posted it first, I'll have to accept his. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Duncan's suggestion, is case you don't want container view's, there is another workaround for your issue. Add you buttons view to the table as your are doing now, implement `scrollViewDidScroll` method of  `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and alter your button's view's `origin.y` according to the `contentOffset` of the table. And, don't forget to give some bottom content inset to your table, so that your button view don't overlap anything when scrolled to the bottom. Hope this was helpful. Good luck!